# Can i use webmatrix to publish website

Tags: javascript, html, css, webmatrix

Can i use Webmatrix to publish and edit my websites, i'm am currently using weebly right now and i'm getting bored to login in and out to change my website, So can i edit my website with Webmatrix and publish it from there ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Webmatrix works similarly to visual studio, you can edit the code of your website, you can run the website locally, **also you can publish your site quite easily**. 
I don't use weebly, but from a quick search, I found that it's possible to get the website files,
so you can open the website using webmatrix, but you'll only be able to work with your site's code(the html/php/etc code).

Comment: yeah, but is there an hosting provider that supports this ?

Comment: Sure, when I worked with webmatrix, I used cytanium ([link](http://www.cytanium.com/free-webmatrix-hosting/)) , it's a free hosting provider that supports webmatrix publishing, and I know that there are a lot of other ones that do the same, you should google it.